# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in \node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, dialogflow-es, chatbot

- I used **npm package react-chatbot-kit**
- and **scaffold (Create React App)**
- to create chatbot and want to connect it with Dialogflow API
- followed the tutorial of dialogflow API: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api
- BUT, always got this error.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 20:24-48
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\Yufan Lu\MA Yufan\PriChat\test\my-chatbot-app\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

*ActionProvider.js*

```
import { SessionsClient } from '@google-cloud/dialogflow-cx';

class ActionProvider {
  constructor(
   createChatBotMessage,
   setStateFunc,
   createClientMessage,
   stateRef,
   createCustomMessage,
   ...rest
 ) {
   this.createChatBotMessage = createChatBotMessage;
   this.setState = setStateFunc;
   this.createClientMessage = createClientMessage;
   this.stateRef = stateRef;
   this.createCustomMessage = createCustomMessage;
   this.dialogflowClient = new SessionsClient();
 }

 async handleUserInput(userInput) { //using dialogflow
  const sessionId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  const sessionPath = this.dialogflowClient.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
    'yufantest-bmqj',//project id
    'global',//location
    '6f2db33e-1f23-462d-a8c8-a5a4adf1f21d',//agentid
    sessionId//sessionid
  );
  const languageCode = 'en'; 
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: userInput,
      },
      languageCode,
    },
  };
  const [response] = await this.dialogflowClient.detectIntent(request);

  // process response
  for (const message of response.queryResult.responseMessages) {
    if (message.text) {
      const botReply = message.text.text;
      const chatMessage = this.createChatBotMessage(botReply);

      // Refresh the chat interface
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        messages: [...prevState.messages, chatMessage],
      }));
    }
  }

  
}
```

**config.js**

```
import React from "react";
//import { createChatBotMessage } from "react-chatbot-kit";
import BotAvatar from "../component/ChatbotAvatar";
import Todos from '../component/Todos/Todos' ;
import ActionProvider from "./ActionProvider";
import MessageParser from "./MessageParser"; 

const config = {
  botName:"PriChat",
  initialMessages: [],//for dialogflow
  //initialMessages:[createChatBotMessage(`Hello! I'm PriChat! How can I help you?`)],
  customComponents:{
    BotAvatar:(props)=><BotAvatar{...props}/>
  },
  customStyles:{
    
    botMessageBox:{
      backgroundColor:"green",
    },
    chatButton:{
      backgroundColor:"green",
    },
  },
  state:{ 
    todos:[]
  },
  widgets:[
    {
      widgetName:"todos",
      widgetFunc:(props)=><Todos {...props}/>,
      mapStateToProps:["todos"],
    }
  ],
  //Following is only for dialogflow API
  actionProvider: new ActionProvider(), 
  messageParser: new MessageParser(), 
};


export default config
```

**MessagParser.js**

```
class MessageParser{
  constructor(actionProvider,state){
    this.actionProvider=actionProvider;
    this.state=state;
  }
parse(message){ //take message to help chatbot what can it do in next step
    console.log(message)
    console.log("parse is running.");
    const loweracse=message.toLowerCase()
    console.log(this.state)
    if(loweracse.includes("hello world")){
      this.actionProvider.helloWorldHandler()
    }else if(loweracse.includes("todos")){
      this.actionProvider.todoHandler();
    }else{
      this.actionProvider.handleUserInput();
    }
    
}
}
export default MessageParser;
```

**config.override.js**

**tried use child_process: 'false'or 'empty' . It can't help.**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.resolve.fallback = {
    ...config.resolve.fallback,
    crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
    path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
    querystring: require.resolve("querystring-es3"),
    os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
    url: require.resolve("url/"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    fs: require.resolve("browserify-fs"),
    child_process: 'false', 
    
  };
  return config;
};
```

- tried use child_process: 'false'or 'empty' . It can't help.
- delete the code related to dialogflow, the chatbot can work very well.
- didn't add webhook. it is neccessary?